# React Navigation swipe between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation on React Native, how do I swipe between multiple screens?

I can only find an onPress solution that navigates me to a specific screen on button press, but I would like to just swipe left and right as well.

Your help would be super appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I think you are willing to create a slider between screens

I think you can use `react-native-snap-carousel`

```
    import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
 
export class MyCarousel extends Component {
 
    _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.slide}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
 
    render () {
        return (
            <Carousel
              ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
              data={this.state.entries}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
              itemWidth={itemWidth}
            />
        );
    }
}
```